# What term is the EASA equivalent of the DER in the FAA safety assurance process?

Tags: safety, terminology, easa-regulations, easa

When the FAA approves a hardware or software (or mixed) system for use in an aircraft requiring Type Certification, A Designated Engineering Representative (DER) is selected to work with the developers and apply the safety assurance guidelines (or other alternative means of compliance) needed for approval. Although the DER is not the final authority granting approval, *de facto* if you fail to satisfy the DER you won't get approval, and if the DER finds that all needed guidelines have been met and all evidence is in order, you probably will.

The EASA process in Europe is very similar, but many of the acronyms and terms they use are different, which brings me to the question:

What is the European (EASA) equivalent of what in America we call the Design Engineering Representative (DER)?

Comment: I posted an answer but just noticed you were looking for EASA equivalent of FAA, not FAA equivalent of EASA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest EASA equivalent would be the Design Organisation Approval (DOA). According to [EASA](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/aircraft-products/design-organisations/design-organisations-approvals):

> A Design Organisation Approval is the recognition that a Design Organisation complies with the requirements of Part 21 Subpart J.
>
> Privileges: A DOA holder can
>
> - Perform design activities within the scope of approval
> - Have compliance documents accepted by the Agency without further verification
> - Perform activities independently from the Agency

Comment: Is the DOA generally an organization that develops systems [so that for example Airbus might be a DOA], or an individual or organization that can be hired by such developers to help them meet the requirements and gain approval?

Comment: Well, this answer gave me the info I needed to track down what a DOA is and how it differs from a DER.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that a DOA is specific to a big or small field. A company may hold a DOA for a specific type of minor modifications, or for design of a full aircraft.

Comment: Also note that a similar mechanism, the POA, exist for production approval